# Can I create a disk in memory for backups?

Tags: memory, tmpfs

The biggest problem I have with my site is the 4 backup periods throughout the day where load will inevitably go above 50.

I am using nice and ionice to try and reduce the impact but to only limited success.

As I immediately copy my backup to an S3 bucket as soon as its completed followed by a deletion of the files, I'm wondering if I can create a memory based disk?

I usually have 25GB free memory (I over specced) and my uncompressed db is 17GB and my compressed is 6GB. I use xtrabackup stream and compress.

If the stream was to memory and not disk I think that would take a lot of load off the system as a whole.

Does this seem viable?

**EDIT 1** something like tmpfs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs

Comment: Generally you would do one full backup during low load hours then incremental multiple times during the day.

Comment: I'm not sure this will automatically help, given that Linux will be using memory to be buffering your write to local disc anyway.  You may well find that it's the *read* load that's blocking your system, and improving the backup *write* load won't help that.  At least you should better understand which aspect of the backup load is stressing your system before you fix only one part of it.

Answer (score 6):

Of course, you can take something like Starwinds RAM disk to create the local drive based on the RAM. I haven't heard such configuration but it should work. As for the future needs, I would recommend you to get another server for the backup purposes.
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/high-performance-ram-disk-emulator

Comment: I was thinking more like tmpfs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs

Comment: It’s the same idea...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use tmpfs like this:

```
mkdir /mnt/rd
mount -t tmpfs -o size=20g tmpfs /mnt/rd
```